# SonicWall TZ210 PPPoE on WAN interface, need transparent bridging to DMZ

Tags: firewall, pppoe, sonicwall

I've got a SonicWall TZ210 which connects to the WAN via PPPoE on the X1 interface. I've got a /29 subnet routed into the box, and everything is running fine.

Now, I need to route one of the WAN IP addresses directly to an internal machine without any NAT being performed on the firewall.

I've set up a test network in which I assign an interface as part of the DMZ zone and set the interface to Transparent IP Mode, set the WAN IP up on a test Ubunutu box connected to that interface, and everything is running fine.

However, when I come to replicate this on the live TZ210, which has PPPoE on the WAN interface, it gives me an error `Error: Index of the interface.: Bridged-to interface must have static IP assignment`, meaning this configuration won't work because of PPPoE.

What's the best route forwards with this?

Comment: I'm curious, why can't you run NAT?

Comment: It's for a MS Lync server, and NAT is buggering up the SIP traffic.

Comment: I am not sure your requested pppoe config is supposed to work.  Generally something like a session border controller is used to make NAT work with Lync in this scenario;  I am not sure sonicwall has SBC functionality

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution? put a **router** in the WAN, without NAT, and you'll use your L2B mode.

You'll *lose one IP* (Router LAN/WAN) but it'll give give you a static interface and clean config!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put a device in the DMZ you will need to assign another physical interface to the DMZ. The error is telling you the DMZ interface needs a static IP.

If all the hosts behind the firewall are public visible (public IPs) then you just need to setup firewall rules. Otherwise you will need to build a DMZ where you static assign some IPs. Also note the host must be added as a host with a static entry.